# iOS OpenGL drawing lines : Not anti-aliasing

Tags: ios, opengl-es

I'm trying to render  a waveform in an EAGLContext View, and I can't for the life of me get it to anti-alias. Is anything clearly wrong with my OpenGL Code? Is anymore information required?

```
 glLineWidth( 0.4f);// -  pass * 1.0f);
    glHint(GL_LINE_SMOOTH_HINT, GL_NICEST);
    glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
    glEnable(GL_BLEND);
    glEnable(GL_LINE_SMOOTH);


   glColor4f(1., 1., 1., 1.);

    // Set up vertex pointer,
    glVertexPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 0, oscilLine);
    // and draw the line.
    glDrawArrays(GL_LINE_STRIP, 0, kDefaultDrawSamples);
```

[image]

Comment: You need to either use a Shader or do some Multisampling, [try reading this](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Multisampling)!

Answer (score 0):

> Is anything clearly wrong with my OpenGL Code?

```
glHint(GL_POINT_SMOOTH_HINT, GL_NICEST);
       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Try changing this to GL_LINE_SMOOTH_HINT?

Also, since you're using the deprecated 1.x APIs you should use glGet with GL_LINE_WIDTH_RANGE and GL_LINE_WIDTH_GRANULARITY to verify that the 0.4 value is actually a supported width.  You also need to ensure that the rendering target you've created has bits for an alpha channel.  Can you add the context creation code?

Finally, it's not quite canon, but according to [this article](http://jitsik.com/wordpress/?p=80) this mechanism of line smoothing doesn't work on iOS devices, though it apparently may on the simulator.

Comment: Naa... didn't work. It did look wrong though. I'm updating my post to reflect that change.